# remove text from multiple spans having same id

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple spans

```
<span id ="myId">data1</span>
<span id ="myId">data2</span>
<span id ="myId">data3</span>
<span id ="myId">data4</span>
<span id ="myId">data5</span>
```

I want to delete text inside all span on single button click.

I tried this on button click in javascript

```
document.getElementById("myId").innerHTML = "";
```

but it is removing text from only 1st span

Comment: Dont give same ID to more than one one tag, use class instead

Comment: Ids are meant to be unique...

Comment: don't use same id for multiple elements. Assign a class and access using `getElementsByClassName('class')` or by using `getElementsByTagName('span')`.

Comment: You should never have same ids for many elements. Use class instead and then you can select all at once and do whatever you want

Comment: You would get all of the elements in nodeList with: document.querySelectorAll("#myId"); . But like n+1 comments - you're supposed to use classes instead of ids.

Comment: @hakre This is not a duplicate of this question, even if my answer does correlate well with that question.

Comment: @SweetieBelle: Right, I stand corrected. That duplicate only related. Infact, you can use just this: [`document.querySelectorAll("#myId").innerHTML = '';`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508979/367456) - I guess this comes pretty close to what the OP wants.

Comment: @hakre You could, but that doesn't solve the broken DOM. :D

Comment: DOM is not broken by that. You just query the attribute, not the ID, that simple it is. It is just an understanding problem. The attribute might have been "misused" here, however, if it is not used at all (e.g. ID myId is not required in DOM ID), you can not misuse it. And no, DOM is not broken, it's just unspecified which element has that ID, you can assign it manually to ensure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont give same ID to more than one one tag, use class instead

```
  <span class ="myId">data1</span>
  <span class ="myId">data2</span>
  <span class ="myId">data3</span>
  <span class ="myId">data4</span>
  <span class ="myId">data5</span>
```

call this function to clear

```
function clearAll()
{
    var ele= document.getElementsByClassName("myId");
    for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
    {
      ele[i].innerHTML='';
    }
}
```

Comment: @vaibhav you can allocate ID's and classes to elements, but, as Shadow and others have said, ID's must be unique on the page

Comment: @JezD: id attribute values must not be unique to query them. E.g. CSS does for a reason look for the attribute value, not the DOM ID. This is equally well possible with javascript and innerHTML as well: [`document.querySelectorAll("#myId").innerHTML = '';`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18508979/367456) - I mean while we are hair-splitting here :)

Answer (score 9):

### IDs are unique, Classes are repeatable

The purpose of an `id` in HTML is to identify a unique element on the page. If you want to apply similar styles or use similar scripts on multiple elements, use a `class` instead:

```
<span class="myClass">data1</span>
<span class="myClass">data2</span>
<span class="myClass">data3</span>
<span class="myClass">data4</span>
<span class="myClass">data5</span>

<input type="button" id="clearbutton" value="Clear Data">
```

### Now let's remove the text

Now, you can select all of these elements and set their text to anything you want. This example uses jQuery, which I recommend because older versions of IE don't support `getElementsByClassName`:

```
$('#clearbutton').click(function() {
    $('.myClass').text('');
});
```

[Link to Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HHbaN/) | [Link to jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

### Or in Vanilla JS

If you're not worried about supporting IE, you can do this with vanilla JavaScript:

```
function clearSpans() {
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");
    for(var i=0; i < spans.length; i++) ele[i].innerHTML='';
}
```

[Link to Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H3VVr/)

### Note: You can add `getElementsByClassName` to IE

I wouldn't recommend doing this because it's simpler and more widely accepted to just use jQuery, but there have been attempts to support older IEs for this function:

```
onload=function(){
if (document.getElementsByClassName == undefined) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(className)
    {
        var hasClassName = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + className + "(?:$|\\s)");
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var results = [];

        var element;
        for (var i = 0; (element = allElements[i]) != null; i++) {
            var elementClass = element.className;
            if (elementClass && elementClass.indexOf(className) != -1 && hasClassName.test(elementClass))
                results.push(element);
        }

        return results;
    }
}
}
```

[Link to source](http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2182479&postcount=4)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a DOM method that relies to the DOM of ID, that is, per DOM, there can only be one element with the same ID.

However, you do not use the id attribute that way in your HTML, so instead you are looking for the selector to query all elements with the id myId, you perhaps know it from CSS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#myId").innerHTML = '';
```

This does not work out of the box, you also need to add the `innerHTML` setter to the `NodeList` prototype, but that is easy:

```
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "innerHTML", {
    set: function (html) {        
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
            this[i].innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
});
```

You find the online demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pj4HD/

Answer (score 0):

```
   var spans=document.getElementsByTagName("span");
   for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++){
     if(spans[i].id=="myId"){
      spans[i].innerHTML="";
     }
   }
```

Although I suggest you don't keep same IDs

http://jsfiddle.net/YysRp/

Comment: This is a painfully inefficient way to do this.

Comment: @SweetieBelle for this yea, but there are times when one get data xmls with same ids, such code works very well for such situations, it is an option that is worth knowing :)